# Failed errors occur during Passing the test class in sandbox.Please suggest me how to solve it with writing the code for it

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test

Here is the Rest Lead apex controller:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/v2/setLead/*')
global with sharing class REST_Lead_Controller {

    @HttpPost
    global static String createLead(String email, String phone, String fname, String lname){

        List<Lead> anct = [SELECT Id from Lead  WHERE Email = :email]; 

        /* If PersonAccount's record does not exist */               
        if(anct.size() == 0){ 

            Lead lead = new Lead();
            List<String> temp = email.split('@');
            lead.FirstName = fname;
            lead.LastName = lname;
            lead.Email = email;      
            lead.Company = 'mcnabb';    
            lead.Status = 'Open'; 
            insert lead;
            return 'Added';


        }else if(phone != 'NA'){

        /* If PersonAccount's record already exist */                
            Lead lead= [SELECT Id, Phone, FirstName, LastName, Email, Company from Lead  WHERE Email   = :email];
            lead.Phone = phone; 
            lead.FirstName = fname;
            lead.LastName = lname;
            update lead;
            return 'Updated';
        }else{

             return 'Exist';
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the test class of the above controller:

```
@isTest
public class REST_Lead_Controller_Test {
    static testMethod void testcreateLead(){ 
       Test.startTest();
       String email= 'xx@gmail.com';
       String phone= '9878987659';
       String fname='gdf';
       String lname='dfg';

        System.RestContext.request = new RestRequest();
        RestContext.request.requestURI = '/v2/setLead/';

        List<Lead> anct = [SELECT Id from Lead WHERE Email = :email];

        String act = REST_Lead_Controller.createLead(email, phone, fname, lname);
           /* If PersonAccount's record does not exist */               
           Lead ant = new Lead();
           List<String> temp = email.split('@');
           ant.FirstName = fname;
           ant.LastName = lname;
           ant.Email = email;  
           ant.Company = 'mcnabb';
           ant.Status = 'Open';
           insert ant;
           System.assertEquals('Added', act);
           Test.stopTest();
    }

    static testMethod void testcreateLeadone(){

        Test.startTest();
        String email='abc@gmail.com';
        String fname='abc';
        String lname='qwe';
        String phone='9878987658';

        Lead actt = [SELECT Id, Phone, FirstName, LastName, Email, Company from Lead  WHERE Email   = :email];
        String act = REST_Lead_Controller.createLead(email, phone, fname, lname);
           actt.FirstName = fname;
           actt.LastName = lname;
           actt.Phone = phone;
        update actt;
        System.assertEquals('Updated', act);
        Test.stopTest();
    }

     static testMethod void testcreateLeadtwo(){ 

        Test.startTest();
        String email='';
        String fname='';
        String lname='';
        String phone='NA';
        String act = REST_Lead_Controller.createLead(email, phone, fname, lname);
        System.assertEquals('Exist', act);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

following are the problems/error that failed the test class method during testing:

> 1). System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
>       **in**
>       Class.REST_Lead_Controller_Test.testcreateLeadone: line 37, column 1.
>
> 2). System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0;
>   first error:         REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are
>   missing: [LastName]: [LastName]
>       **in**
>       Class.REST_Lead_Controller.createLead: line 19, column 1
>       Class.REST_Lead_Controller_Test.testcreateLeadtwo: line 54, column 1

**testcreateLead** method in test class is used to call the (if condition) of the controller.

**testcreateLeadone** method in test class is used to call the (else if condition) of the controller.

**testcreateLeadtwo** method in test class is used to call the (else condition) of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

1. make your line 37 as below; (add **limit 1**)
   [SELECT Id, Phone, FirstName, LastName, Email, Company from Lead  WHERE Email   = :email LIMIT 1];
2. your line 52 must have a value as it is a **mandatory field**

---

Please see the working code below.

```
@isTest
public class REST_Lead_Controller_Test {
    static testMethod void testcreateLead(){ 
        Test.startTest();
        String email= 'xx@gmail.com';
        String phone= '9878987659';
        String fname='gdf';
        String lname='dfg';

        System.RestContext.request = new RestRequest();
        RestContext.request.requestURI = '/v2/setLead/';

        List<Lead> anct = [SELECT Id from Lead WHERE Email = :email];

        String act = REST_Lead_Controller.createLead(email, phone, fname, lname);
        /* If PersonAccount's record does not exist */               
        Lead ant = new Lead();
        List<String> temp = email.split('@');
        ant.FirstName = fname;
        ant.LastName = lname;
        ant.Email = email;  
        ant.Company = 'mcnabb';
        ant.Status = 'Open';
        insert ant;
        System.assertEquals('Added', act);
        Test.stopTest();
    }

    static testMethod void testcreateLeadone(){

        Test.startTest();
        String email='abc@gmail.com';
        String fname='abc';
        String lname='qwe';
        String phone='9878987658';

        // you need to have a test data record inserted in order to retrieve a one and update, otherwise you will get the Error:
        // System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
        insert(new Lead (Email = 'abc@gmail.com',Company = 'ACB(Pty) Ltd', FirstName = 'test fn', LastName = 'test ln'));

        Lead actt = [SELECT Id, Phone, FirstName, LastName, Email, Company from Lead  WHERE Email   = :email LIMIT 1];
        String act = REST_Lead_Controller.createLead(email, phone, fname, lname);
        actt.FirstName = fname;
        actt.LastName = lname;
        actt.Phone = phone;
        update actt;
        System.assertEquals('Updated', act);
        Test.stopTest();
    }

    static testMethod void testcreateLeadtwo(){ 
        // you need to have an existing record in order to get this test case passed 
        insert(new Lead (Email = 'abc@gmail.com',Company = 'ACB(Pty) Ltd', FirstName = 'test fn', LastName = 'test ln'));
        Test.startTest();
        String email='abc@gmail.com';
        String fname='';
        String lname='';
        String phone='NA';
        String act = REST_Lead_Controller.createLead(email, phone, fname, lname);
        System.assertEquals('Exist', act);
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: It will not work. please studied the code completely and help me.it shows the problem in assertion of second and third method in test class. i.e in the second method assertion expect: Update, but it shows Added. In third method assertion expect: Exist, but it shows Added. It means that it calls on if statement in the controller side.

Comment: Please anyone can create the test class of the above apex controller correctly. I am suffering from last two weeks to create its test class so that it must be passed in both sandbax as well as in the production.

Comment: @yyy - The errors in your question are not due to assertions. If your question is no longer valid you may want to post a new question.